Kotlin ReadWriteProperty : Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead
Since i am not yet good in generics I would like to ask:
error
Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead
What am i missing? enumValueOf() Not working ...
class EnumSharedPreferenceProperty<T : Enum<T>>(
    private val pref: SharedPreferences,
    private val name: String,
) : ReadWriteProperty<Any, T> {


    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        val enumName = pref.getString(name, "").orEmpty()
        return enumValueOf(enumName)
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        pref.edit().putString(name, value.name).commit()
    }
}


You are trying to call a Kotlin function with a reified type parameter when the type for doing so is not available. That isn't going to compile and you need another approach.
Reified type parameters
This is a Kotlin feature where the compiler keeps track of a concrete ("reified") type using inline functions, leading to more elegant APIs and a reduced use of reflection. However if you do not have access to the concrete class at the call site and instead only have the target class inside a variable (or, as in your example, no class at all), you can't call such a function.
So, such a call would be possible:
enum class MyEnum { ONE, TWO }

fun main() {
    println(enumValueOf<MyEnum>("ONE"))
}

Here I concretely have access to MyEnum, so the call is successful.
Your example
In your example, it does not appear possible to get your hands on a concrete enum class. To do so would involve function inlining with a reified type parameter. Your proposed delegation uses a class to perform the delegation though, and classes cannot accept reified types in Kotlin.
Accessing enum value using reflection on JVM
Still, there is a way to achieve what you want if you are working on the JVM, using Java reflection1.
First you'd need to capture the enum class instance somehow in the constructor of the class2:
class EnumSharedPreferenceProperty<T : Enum<T>>(
    private val enumClass: KClass<T>,
    // ...
)

Then you could use or adapt the following function, which uses Java reflection to get hold of an enum instance3:
fun <E : Enum<*>> enumValueOf(name: String, enumClass: KClass<E>): E {
    return enumClass.java.enumConstants
        ?.singleOrNull { eachEnumValue -> eachEnumValue.name == name }
        ?: error("No enum of value $name found in class $enumClass")
}

And call it as follows instead of the regular enumValueOf function:
return enumValueOf(enumName, enumClass)


1 If you are working on multiple or other platforms, there may well be a way to reproduce such a function on those platforms if you are eager enough to get this approach working, using those platforms' reflection facilities
2 Funnily enough, using an inline function with a reified type parameter could be an elegant way of doing so, and calling it when you set the delegated property, but perhaps that's getting a bit out of the scope of the question
3 I wrote a little test/proof of this function on Kotlin playground
